# Cryptographic hash functions and personal password management

Tags: passwords, cryptography, password-management, password-cracking

Background: I've always reused same username/password on all websites and got hacked regularly. I am considering using a password manager, but I don't like the need of storing a database. So I came up with my own idea.

Assume there are multiple services for which one needs to be able to recover a password, each having a unique name `name_i` - a short string. You pick a `master_password`. Let `h(x)` be the output of a cryptographic hash function for string `x` and `+` denote concatenation. Then one can choose their password for service `name_i` to be `h(master_password+name_i)`.

Knowing the name and `master_password` it is trivial to recover password for any given service. By cryptographic hash function definition, even when a subset of passwords gets leaked, the master password an the rest of the passwords should be safe.

Is the above reasoning correct and could this be a viable way of managing my own passwords?

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55592/password-managers-encrypted-database-vs-hashing-strategy for a similar question.

Comment: "I don't like the need of storing a database" so use a cloud-based password manager that provides zero-trust end-to-end encryption (e.g. BitWarden, 1Password, LastPass, etc.). I guarantee you this will be safer _and_ more convenient than your proposed system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've actually built a cryptographically secure password manager which generated passwords from a main password, a string, and a set of parameter values.  This is not as trivial as it seems, and I'd recommend using a regular password manager (I like 1Password) instead.  Here's why:

- Your proposed solution is not secure.  When using a password as the source of entropy, it's recommended to use salt, which you have no way of storing, and you need to use a suitable password hashing function, not just concatenation with a cryptographic hash.  You'd need to at least switch to Argon2id or scrypt or some other suitable function.
- Simply using the hash output will not work for many websites.  If the output is hex, it won't contain both upper- and lowercase letters or special characters, which many sites require, and some sites limit strings to a certain number of characters, and a 64-character hex output will be too long.  Some sites require a special character, but it has to be from a limited set.  You need a way to take your hash and generate a string of a specified length and composition.
- You also need a way to encode arbitrary existing passwords.  While sharing accounts is not a good security practice, in some cases it will be required.  Perhaps you and your partner share a credit card, but the company allows only one account to manage it.  Thus, you need to be able to take an existing password and store it using your password manager.
- You need a way to change passwords for a site.  If a site is compromised, they may force you to reset your password, and you'd need to pick a new one.  Using just the site name won't work here, and you'd need to include some sort of version number for the password, which requires that you store that somewhere.
- Most cell phones don't offer general purpose terminal commands or hash programs, so you won't be able to perform this functionality on your phone.  If you're using secure passwords, typing a long password in from your computer can be very difficult.

In the ideal world, where any cryptographically secure string were allowed as a password and sites could never be compromised, this might be a viable approach with a change to the structure of the algorithm.  However, your design has serious practical problems due to real world constraints.  I even found my design, which addressed all of these issues by storing a set of site names and parameters, to be functionally difficult to use, which is why I switched to 1Password.  I would strongly encourage you to use a standard, secure, reputable tool for this, whether it stores data in the cloud or on your local machine, to ensure that it's secure and flexible enough to meet your needs.